# Client.Error.MessageSend - Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Status 404: url:

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3, amf

I am a beginner in Flex. I was trying out a Flex-Spring-Hibernate-Java project, which would fetch the records from database and show it in a grid.

But, when I try to open my application, I get the following error :

> ?[RPC Fault faultString="Send failed"
>   faultCode="Client.Error.MessageSend"
>   faultDetail="Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.Failed:
>   HTTP: Status 404: url:
>   '`http://localhost:8080/demo/spring/messagebroker/amf`'"]

What this error is regarding ?

*PS : I saw the other related error links similar to this error, but that didn't help me out.*

Other Project related details :-

**ContextWebRoot : Statistics ( name of my project )**

Comment: IT looks like a 'standard' 404 error; which in web terms means "page not found".  Does the URL http://localhost:8080/demo/spring/messagebroker/amf load in your browser?  Or not; then the issue is a server configuration issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was trying the project sample from here .. http://www.webdbtips.com/68807/ .. Nope, that url leads to 404 on my web browser. I named the combined Flex-Java project using BlazeDS as "Statistics"

Comment: Which configuration am I missing or missed out ?

Comment: if the url is 404'ing in your browser, then flash won't be able to get it either :) - are you running a local server, like WAMP or EasyPHP?

Comment: I assume you have a web server set up on your local machine at port 8080?  It sounds like something is wrong w/ your AMF endpoint URL; so AMF is misconfigured.  I have no idea how to direct you from here, though.  @divillysausages If he is using Spring-Hibernate-Java; then he won't be running WAMP or EasyPHP.

Comment: I am running the project on Tomcat 7 in Eclipse Helios.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP: Status 404 clearly means the server is not able to find the page you're looking for.

The URL you're using is invalid.
`http://localhost:8080/demo/spring/messagebroker/amf`

Maybe you are missing a trailing slash or something.

For the list of HTTP error codes:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error